# Does type constructor implement Fn?

Tags: rust

I am not sure that the title of my question is correct since I am not sure where exactly placed. 
Let say I have a code which looks like:

```rust
struct MyWrapper(u64);

fn my_func<F>(f: F, n: u64) -> MyWrapper
where
    F: Fn(u64) -> MyWrapper,
{
    f(n)
}

fn main() {
    my_func(MyWrapper, 3);
}
```

It compiles and works so it looks like `MyWrapper` implements trait `Fn`.

However, should I try to use it in a trait.

```rust
struct MyWrapper(u64);

trait MyTrait
where
    Self: Fn(u64) -> MyWrapper,
{
}

impl MyTrait for MyWrapper{}
```

I get an error

```
16 | impl MyTrait for MyWrapper{};
   |      ^^^^^^^ expected an `Fn<(u64,)>` closure, found `MyWrapper`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::ops::Fn<(u64,)>` is not implemented for `MyWrapper`
```

It was a more theoretical question.

Speaking practicaly, what I am trying to achieve is to implement trait like this

Edit: 
I have rightfully pointed out that my example is not full, so there is a fixed version.

```
pub enum Status {
    New,
    Cancelled,
}

struct NewTransaction(u64);

struct CancelledTransaction(u64);

fn get_by_status(id: &str, status: Status) -> Result<u64, ()> {
    Ok(3)
}

pub trait Transaction
where
    Self: std::marker::Sized,
{
    const status: Status;
    fn get(id: &str) -> Result<Self, ()>;
}

impl Transaction for NewTransaction {
    const status: Status = Status::New;
    fn get(id: &str) -> Result<Self, ()> {
        get_by_status(id, Self::status).map(Self)
    }
}

impl Transaction for CancelledTransaction {
    const status: Status = Status::Cancelled;
    fn get(id: &str) -> Result<Self, ()> {
        get_by_status(id, Self::status).map(Self)
    }
}
```

This code compiles, but as you can see - all implementations of Transaction for every type are *exactly* the same, so it seems totally reasonable to move this implementation as a default. Like this

```rust
pub trait Transaction
where
    Self: std::marker::Sized,
{
    const status: Status;
    fn get(id: &str) -> Result<Self, ()> {
        get_by_status(id, Self::status).map(Self)
    }
}

impl Transaction for NewTransaction {
    const status: Status = Status::New;
}

impl Transaction for CancelledTransaction {
    const status: Status = Status::Cancelled;
}
```

And here I got a complain that Self cannot be used as a Value. 
I've tried to fix it by introducing a condition `where Self: Fn(u32) -> Self` on trait but it didn't work either.

Edit: 
In the end, I implemented the idea suggested by Sven Marnach - added a method `new` and required all struct to implement this method.  It still looks quite strange, since the implementation is exactly the same for all structures, but it works.

```rust
pub trait Transaction
where
    Self: std::marker::Sized,
{
    const status: Status;
    fn new(n: u64) -> Self;
    fn get(id: &str) -> Result<Self, ()> {
        get_by_status(id, Self::status).map(Self::new)
    }
}

impl Transaction for NewTransaction {
    const status: Status = Status::New;
    fn new(n: u64) -> Self {
        Self(n)
    }
}
```

Thanks everyone for answers!

Comment: "Speaking practicaly, what I am trying to achieve is to implement trait like this" please complete the real case you want, currently it's far away from [mcve]

Comment: `impl MyTrait for MyWrapper{};` is not syntactically correct: remove the semi-colon and you'll still obtain the error message that you claim.

Comment: `trait MyTrait where Self: ...` should usually be written as `trait MyTrait: ...`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach It's interesting.  I agree, but when compiler gives a hint it suggests a `where` construction here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The constructor of a tuple-like struct or enum variant is actually treated as a *function name* when used in a context where a value rather than a type is expected, and it is treated as the *type* it names in a context where a type is expected.

When calling `my_func(MyWrapper, 3)`, the name `MyWrapper` denotes a function with a function item type that coerces to the function pointer type `fn(u64) -> MyWrapper`. In particular, the item type implements the trait `Fn(u64) -> MyWrapper`.

In the code `impl MyTrait for MyWrapper {}`, however, `MyWrapper` denotes the struct type it declares. That type is completely different from the type of `MyWrapper` when used in a value context, and it does not implement the `Fn(u64) -> MyWrapper` trait.

In your actual use case, I believe the easiest solution is to require a `new()` method with the desired prototype on the type:

```
trait Payment {
   const status: Status;
   fn new(x: u64) -> Self;
   fn get(id: u64) -> Result<Self, Error> {
       get_by_status(Self::status, id).map(Self::new)
   }
}
```

Implementors of `Payment` will only need to provide `new()` method with the desired prototype, but will inherit the default implementation of `get()`.

Answer (score 2):

> It compiles and works so it looks like `MyWrapper` implements trait `Fn`.

A quick and dirty way to know the type of something in Rust is to do:

```rust
struct MyWrapper(u64);

fn main() {
    let mut foo = MyWrapper;
    foo = ();
}
```

This produces an error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:5:11
  |
5 |     foo = ();
  |           ^^ expected fn item, found ()
  |
  = note: expected type `fn(u64) -> MyWrapper {MyWrapper}`
             found type `()`
```

As you can see `foo` is **not** a `MyWrapper` structure so `MyWrapper` does not implement `Fn` like you thought it would.

I agree this can be confusing, see [`tuple struct case`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/struct-expr.html#tuple-struct-expression):

> A struct expression with fields enclosed in parentheses constructs a tuple struct. Though it is listed here as a specific expression for completeness, it is equivalent to a [call expression](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/call-expr.html) to the tuple struct's constructor. For example:

```rust
struct Position(i32, i32, i32);
Position(0, 0, 0);  // Typical way of creating a tuple struct.
let c = Position;  // `c` is a function that takes 3 arguments.
let pos = c(8, 6, 7);  // Creates a `Position` value.
```

---

> Speaking practically, what I am trying to achieve is to implement trait like this

Your example is not complete so my answer is not final but I don't think it's possible to do what you want.